# How to find the given any date (ex. 2018-11-05 00:30:27.863) is greater than 24 hours or it exceeded 24 hours from that date in SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to send or trigger a mail where, given specified date exceeded 24 hour.like it should send  please take any action after 24 hours in stored procedure.

```
  DATEADD(day, -1,Getdate()) or (now() +interval 1 day)
```

These I have used but not able to see the expected output

I have tried

```
 select * from table where date >= DATEADD(day, -1,Getdate()) 

 where date ex. 2018-11-05 00:30:27.863
```

Comment: date <= DATEADD(day, -1,Getdate())

Comment: Thank you for answer and For finding the date which exceeded 48 hours is Date<= [DATEADD(day, -2, Getdate()) ] and date which exceeded 72 hours is Date<= [DATEADD(day, -3, Getdate()) ] is this correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Your query needs the `<` symbol instead of `>`:

```
select * from table where date <= DATEADD(day, -1, Getdate())
```

because you need `date` to be prior than `Getdate() - 1 day`.
Or:

```
select * from table where Getdate() >= DATEADD(day, 1, date)
```

Comment: but [ DATEADD(day, -1, Getdate()) ] this would give yesterday date and time. so that would be like this 2018-11-05 00:30:27.863 <= 2019-08-08 08:34:14.160 . yes it is less than that date but i need like specified date is greater than 24 hours or not.

Comment: `DATEADD(day, -1, Getdate())` will give yesterdays' date and time and you want `date` to be less than that result so `date` has exceeded 24 hour.

Comment: For finding the date which exceeded 48 hours is Date<= [DATEADD(day, -2, Getdate()) ] and  date which exceeded 72 hours is Date<= [DATEADD(day, -3, Getdate()) ] is this correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DATEDIFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function like below -

```
select * from table where DATEDIFF(hh,dateColumn,GETDATE()) > 24
```